# Fetch token and pass it to render view - React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to fetch the token and pass it to my Apple Map.

```html
const[mapToken, setMapToken] = useState();

    useEffect(()=> {

        getMapToken();

    },[])
    
    const getMapToken = async ()=>{
        const res = await fetch("TokenURL");
        const token = await res.text();
        setMapToken('"'+ token +'"');
    }

//I can see the token value here wrapping by double quotation mark:

    console.log(mapToken);
```

And here is how I rendered it:

```html
   <AppleMaps 
    token={mapToken}
    longitude={storeinfo.longitude}
    latitude={storeinfo.latitude}
    zoomLevel={10}
    height='150px'
    width='500px'
>
</AppleMaps>
```

I can see the token value wrapping by double quotation mark in the console.log. However, when I try to pass it to my map it doesn't work. If I copy what I got from the console.log and replace the token value, it works perfectly. Any ideas?

[The image of my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLaqO.png)

Comment: There's no need to mess around with quotes, it's already a string. By adding the quotes, you end up with a bad token. Use `setMapToken(token);` https://jsfiddle.net/m8yxdjkr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to render AppleMaps when mapToken is available.

```
const [mapToken, setMapToken] = useState('');
    useEffect(()=> {

        getMapToken();
    },[])
    
    const getMapToken = async ()=>{
        const res = await fetch("TokenURL");
        const token = await res.text();
        setMapToken('"'+ token +'"');
    }
```

```
{mapToken.length && <AppleMaps 
   token={mapToken}
   longitude={storeinfo.longitude}
   latitude={storeinfo.latitude}
   zoomLevel={10}
   height='150px'
   width='500px'
>
</AppleMaps>}
```

Comment: mapToken.length is not working but I tried {mapToken && <AppleMaps.......} it works!!! Thank you very much you saved my life.

Comment: If you initialize mapToken with empty string, mapToken.length will work. Will you tick the answer if it works?